# Don't understand results obtained using itertools.permutations()

Tags: python, permutation, graph-theory

This is the code to represent a set of distinct numbers from 0 to 15 in 12 space such that the differences between some adjacent numbers are also distinct.

```
import itertools

list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]

for i in itertools.permutations(list,12):
    a1 = abs(i[0] - i[1])
    b1 = abs(i[0] - i[2])
    a = abs(i[0] - i[3])
    b = abs(i[0] - i[4])
    c = abs(i[0] - i[5])
    d = abs(i[1] - i[6])
    e = abs(i[2] - i[7])
    f = abs(i[3] - i[8])
    g = abs(i[4] - i[9])
    h = abs(i[5] - i[10])
    g1 = abs(i[6] - i[11])
    h1 = abs(i[7] - i[11])
    c1 = abs(i[8] - i[11])
    d1 = abs(i[9] - i[11])
    e1 = abs(i[10] - i[11])
    L= [a1, b1, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, g1, h1, c1, d1, e1]
    if (len(set(L))==15):
        print(i)
        print(L)
```

There seems to be no output for this code but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Reword your question, not possible to understand what your code is supposed to do, maybe show the expected output.

Comment: There are billions of such permutations. How are you sure that it is feasible to brute force it in Python?

Comment: I'm having a hard time proving it, but I feel like you're running up against the pigeon hole principle regarding assigning `[0, 16)` absolute differences uniquely to your pairs.

Comment: Have you made *any* attempt at debugging this yourself?  Printing out the largest value of `len(set(L))` seen so far might be instructive, to see if you're even getting close to 15 distinct differences.

Comment: @Nihal that doesn't prove anything. What about a permutation that starts [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 11, ...]. Then those don't equal

Comment: This program is about graceful labeling of graph.

Comment: Let G be a graph with 8 vertices and 9 edges.Let say i have numbers from [0 to 9] and i have to assign it to 8 vertices of a graph such that the absolute difference of adjacent vertices are all distinct.  And when i run this program i get total 720 ways of doing this . ex : vertices(0,9,8,7,3,4,2,1)  abs. diff [9,8,7,6,4,5,2,3,1].  similarly 720 ways @anand_v.singh

Comment: @JohnColeman i dont know.I have to do this to gracefully label a graph.And i can not do it with pen and paper because there are 21794,57,28,000 calculations , that i have to do.

Comment: When i am running this with 14 distinct deifference i.e.  if (len(set(L))==14): , it is giving output.@jasonharper

Comment: paritosh joshi: Adding just one more element could make it take quite a bit longer.

Comment: Then what should i do ?? I need the output..@martineau

Comment: Not all graphs are [graceful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_labeling). Why do you think that this one is? In any event, surely there are better algorithms for graceful labeling than brute force (which would be sort of like trying to solve the n-queens problem with brute force). Instead, use e.g. a backtracking algorithm.

Comment: Also -- your code would be much more readable if instead of having the structure of your graph implicit in the choice a large number of variables (one for each edge), you used a data structure for your graph (e.g. an adjacency matrix or a list of lists of adjacent vertices). Your code hardwires too many parameters. Finding a graceful labeling (or determining if one doesn't exist) is something that makes sense for any graph, so why not write your code so it can take any graph as input? That way you could develop your code using smaller examples and then apply it to this.

Comment: You just didn't wait long enough.  I let your code run overnight, and had 3954 solutions printed out this morning (and it's still running!).  First one was `(0, 1, 3, 13, 14, 15, 10, 7, 6, 2, 4, 12)`, with differences `[1, 3, 13, 14, 15, 9, 4, 7, 12, 11, 2, 5, 6, 10, 8]`.

Comment: Mine is running too , its around 14000 now @jasonharper

Comment: @JohnColeman i will try!!!! but can you help me optimize this code??

Comment: @paritoshjoshi I wasn't aware of this problem before today. It seems like a hard problem. If you intend to do research on it, it would make sense to first master some of the literature rather than reinvent wheels that were invented with great difficulty years ago. I can across a relatively recent paper called "Graceful Labeling Algorithms and Complexity: A Survey" (https://jims-a.org/index.php/jimsa/article/viewFile/14/pdf_1) which seems like a good place to start learning about the algorithms. To just experiment, you could e.g.  throw a genetic algorithm at the problem and see how it works

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I will learn some of the basics first.@JohnColeman

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach which generates random solutions. It moves all the variable checks into a loop and short-circuits the loop when there is a clash:

```
import itertools, random

labels = list(range(16))
edges = ((0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(1,6),(2,7),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10),(6,11),(7,11),(8,11),(9,11),(10,11))
num_vertices = 12

def solve(labels,edges,num_vertices):
    shuffled_labels = labels[:] #make a copy
    random.shuffle(shuffled_labels)
    for p in itertools.permutations(shuffled_labels,num_vertices):
        differences = [0]*16
        solved = True #innocent until proven guilty
        for i,j in edges:
            difference = abs(p[i]-p[j])
            differences[difference] += 1
            if differences[difference] == 2:
                solved = False
                break #no need to check more edges
        if solved:
            return p
```

One run (of about 1 minute):

```
>>> solve(labels,edges,num_vertices)
(6, 5, 1, 14, 3, 2, 11, 15, 12, 13, 9, 0)
```

This is easily verified to satisfy your constraints.

Here is a generator solution which will yield all possible solutions:

```
def solutions(labels,edges,num_vertices):
    for p in itertools.permutations(labels,num_vertices):
        differences = [0]*16
        solved = True #innocent until proven guilty
        for i,j in edges:
            difference = abs(p[i]-p[j])
            differences[difference] += 1
            if differences[difference] == 2:
                solved = False
                break #no need to check more edges
        if solved:
            yield p
```

Used like e.g.:

```
for p in solutions(labels,edges,num_vertices): print(p)
```

Unlike the random approach which usually returns in less than a minute, the generator churns away for a very long time before it starts yielding results. This suggests that the identity permutation (where this generator starts) is far from being a solution. Still, it does eventually yield permutations (after about 10-15 minutes), with the first one being:

```
(0, 1, 3, 13, 14, 15, 10, 7, 6, 2, 4, 12)
```

(agreeing with the result of @jasonharper).